# Unknown UPnP Entries

Tags: firewall, port, upnp

Was checkout out my Firewall on which I usually have UPnP disabled, but turned it on as a debugging step for an issue I was having.

I just noticed three ports registered that I am unsure where they came from.

```
1    52 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <wanip>      tcp dpt:6524 to:<mylaptop>:6524
1    47 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <wanip>      udp dpt:6524 to:<mylaptop>:6524
26  1400 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <wanip>      tcp dpt:8156 to:<mylaptop>:8156
203 19123 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <wanip>      udp dpt:8156 to:<mylaptop>:8156
1    52 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <wanip>      tcp dpt:8011 to:<mylaptop>:8011
3   160 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <wanip>      udp dpt:8011 to:<mylaptop>:8011
```

In Googling, I have found that ports 8156 and 8011 are known to come from a service known as `EMC2 (Legato) Networker or Sun Solcitice Backup (Official)`; I have never hard of this.

What might be on my system that is opening up these holes in my network?

Comment: Those ports could belong to any software you have installed.  So have verified what software you do have running does not use those ports?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out. I have not knowingly installed anything that should be binding or UPnPing these ports. Spyware?

Comment: The machine to which these entries point is running Windows 8.0, how can I search the windows firewall for specific ports?

Comment: Its possible.  We can't tell you.  I mean right now 0.0.0.0 means that traffic sent/from to that port is going to every address on the network.  Use other relevant software to determine what process is sending said traffic.

Comment: False, the _0.0.0.0_ means any source, with a destination of my WAN IP, is being forwarded to that IP.

Comment: Go to your Windows 8 computer, open Resource Monitor, and look under the Network tab to see what program is using those ports.